# Forcin Nginx to render URI from Rails using Passenger

Tags: nginx, subdomain, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Is it possible to force Nginx to render some URL from Rails app although file exists on server? I want to hide some files based from which subdomain request comes. So I would like to completely avoid direct rendering of file from server.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your public directory empty / move it to another location then all requests will be responded to by rails in the first instance.

You can then use X-Sendfile ( or the nginx equivalent ) to send the file if you want the user to have access to it.